# Reading ora_rowscn with JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jooq

I am trying to get the 'ora_rowscn' pseudo column value from org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDSL, but this class only supports the pseudo columns 'rowid' and 'rownum'.
I cannot find the support for 'ora_rowscn'.

Any ideas how I can get the value I need?

Comment: What jOOQ and Oracle versions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [`OracleDSL.oraRowscn()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/oracle/OracleDSL.html#oraRowscn--) function, which was added in [jOOQ 3.6.0](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3928)